# How to unlock qr codes?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I have spoken to Sable every day for a while and she open now, but, the QR code machine still isn't there.
I have already tried looking at internet sites, and they tell me to do what I've already done.

So how do i get the QR code machine?

Comment: How many days in a row have you done it for? It took me 8 days until she got the QR code scanner.